# Correctly display HTML from JSON

Tags: json, parsing, editorjs

I'm using editor.js [html-parser](https://github.com/pavittarx/editorjs-html) to transform my data from JSON to html.

```
 const edjsParser = edjsHTML();
 let html = edjsParser.parse(JSON.parse(objective));
 console.log(html, "html");
```

It works fines, my html output is now :

```
[
"<img src=\"https://res.cloudinary.com/climact/image/upload/v1647473655/image_7a710834c2.png\" alt=\"Image\" />",
"<h2>Header</h2>",
"<br/>"
]
```

But now, how can I display it on my react page ? When I try to display it using {html} it didnt render as html but as string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert it inside a container, like a `div`, you can use [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml):

```
return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }}></div>;
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't need to join it, simply dangerouslySetInnerHTML works.